# How do I fix this manifest merger issue?

Tags: android, xml, sdk

I tried to run my Unscrambler application, but I received an error about the MinSDK not being high enough for the project. This is the error that I received:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10] AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.navigation.compose" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

My *AndroidManifest.xml* file looks like this right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="androidx.navigation.compose" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

</manifest>
```

Would this be a simple matter of raising the project's MinSDk or switching to a lower version library?

Comment: You can't use Compose itself or Navigation Compose on API 19 devices - the minSdkVersion of those libraries is correctly set to 21.

Comment: So will I need to raise the MinSDK of the project to 21?

Comment: Are you writing a non-Compose user interface for API 19 devices and a Compose user interface only for API 21 and higher devices? Or are you trying to write just a Compose user interface?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Compose, but I set the project MinSDK to 19, so that it will run on most Android devices.

Comment: You've said you've included Navigation Compose, which only works as part of [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). Why are you including that dependency at all?

Comment: The dependency was included in the program which I got from a course I'm taking. The instructor must've put that in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add or change in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you should **never** be using `com.android` dependencies in 2021 - those only pull in the completely deprecated and replaced Support Library dependencies and **not** the AndroidX versions of those dependencies, which are the only ones compatible with the newest versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this there:

```xml
tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.navigation.compose"
```

It will fix your problem.